# Why I can not move a view when it is in the horizontal center and vertical center

Tags: android

Why I can not move a view when it is in the horizontal center and vertical center? For example in the following code first the `imageview` is in the horizontal center and vertical center and now I want using the following code move it upward. But it does not move upward. Of course when the `imageView` is not  in the horizontal center and vertical, I can move it upward,but when first it is in the horizontal center and vertical center, it can not move upward.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
      layoutParams.topMargin = 50;
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to solve my problem and it is the `setMargins` method instead using the `layoutParams.topMargin = 50;`

```
layoutParams.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try setPadding left, right, top and bottom.

```
 layoutParams.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```